# Spectral theorem for bounded self-adjoint operators without lemma of Zorn

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I'm currently studying the spectral theorem for bounded self-adjoint operators, and came across Lemma 2 in section VII.2 from the book "Functional Analysis" by Reed and Simon. It says:

Let $A$ be a self adjoint operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$. Then there is a direct sum decomposition $H=\bigoplus_{n=1}^N H_n$ with $N=1,2,\ldots,$ or $\infty$ so that

1. $A$ leaves each $H_n$ invariant, that is $\psi\in H_n$ implies $A\psi\in H_n$
2. For each $n$, there is a $\phi_n\in H_n$, which is cyclic for $A \upharpoonright H_n$ i.e. $H_n=\overline{\{f(A)\phi_n|f\in C(\sigma(A))\}}$

For the proof, the book says it is "a simple Zornication".

My question is why we need the lemma of Zorn to prove this theorem in a **separable** Hilbert space. For an arbitrary Hilbert space I have no trouble understanding why this is necessary, but in a separable Hilbert space, similar to the Hahn-Banach theorem, I think it is not necessary here. 
Most proofs I found online were similar to that of Reed and Simon, although sometimes in non-separable Hilbert space.

My proof without using the Lemma would be similar to the following:

Choose an orthonormal basis $(e_i)$ of $H$ and define $H_1$ to be the completion of $\{A^n e_1| n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. If $e_2\not \in H_1$ let $\tilde e_2$ be the projection of $e_2$ to $H_1^\perp$ and set $H_2 = \overline{\{A^n \tilde e_2| n\in \mathbb{N}\}}$. Since $\tilde e_2\perp H_1$, we have $(\tilde e_2,A^ne_1) = 0$ and then for all $n,m\in  \mathbb{N}$ we have
$(A^m\tilde e_2,A^n e_1) = (\tilde e_2,A^{m+n}e_1) = 0$ so $H_2\perp H_1$. If $e_2\in H_1$ continue with $e_3$. Similarly we construct spaces $H_3,H_4\ldots$ which are all orthogonal.

Do I make a mistake here or is it just more convenient to use Zorns lemma and state an unconstructive, more general proof of the theorem?

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me, and personally I like it better than a Zorn's lemma approach.  But I think it's really just a matter of taste.

Comment: How can I guarantee that every vector in the space can be finally expressed as the sum of vectors in such a decomposition? Doesn't seems too clear to me

Comment: @PAB: Let $H' = \bigoplus_{n=1}^N H_n$ be the space of those vectors that can be written as a sum of vectors from the $H_n$.  This space is closed, and by construction it contains all the $e_i$, so it is also dense.

Comment: In the next step, how is $H_{3}$ constructed? If $e_{3} \not\in H_{1} \cup H_{2}$ then take $\tilde{e}_{3}$ to be the projection of $e_{3}$ to $(H_{1}\cup H_{2})^{\perp}$? And so on?